# Angular js - Round number to two decimal places on blur

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/nqUPEI?p=preview

I have input type number textbox & need to format its value to two decimal places.

```
For example if 

(1) If user enter 15.656 it should format to 15.66 on blur

(2) If user enter 15.6 it should format to 15.60 on blur

(3) If user enter 15 it should format to 15.00 on blur

Also will be using the textbox value to carry out further with other     textboxes.
```

Comment: You can create a custom directive which would fire on blur.  Follow the link for more information.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. It seems that its not same as my requirement.